# When i press the save button the checkbox didnt stay check

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php 
$options = array(
 'infant'  => '1',
 'mater'    => '2',
 'prees'   => '3',
 'kinder' => '4', );

echo form_open('evals/proc_group'); 
echo form_checkbox('edu_level[]','1', in_array('1', $educational_levels)); echo form_label ('Infantes', 'infant',  array ('class' => 'checkbox_label'));
echo form_checkbox('edu_level[]','2', in_array('2', $educational_levels)); echo form_label ('Maternales', 'mater',  array ('class' => 'checkbox_label'));
echo form_checkbox('edu_level[]','3', in_array('3', $educational_levels)); echo form_label ('Preescolares', 'prees',  array ('class' => 'checkbox_label'));
echo form_checkbox('edu_level[]','4', in_array('4', $educational_levels)); echo form_label ('Kindergarten', 'kinder',  array ('class' => 'checkbox_label')); ?>

<input type="hidden" name="eval_id" value="<?php echo $evaluation->id ?>" />                                   
<div class="clear"></div>                                       
<?php echo form_submit('mysubmit','Guardar Grupo'); ?> 
<div class="clear"></div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

I need the checkboxes stay checked when i press Guardar Grupo. What can i do?

Comment: what actually you want to do ? check boxes are on both sides (i.e. on the form controller/mathod and where the form submits - that is evals/proc_group ?)

Comment: When I click the check boxes I want the boxes stay checked when i go back to home, when i go back to the home screen the boxes didnt stay checked.

Comment: @Jonathan Padilla Do you want the same checkboxes to be checked again after the page reload?

Comment: need to see the controller code ... how are you generating `$education_levels`? how are you storing the data after submit?

Comment: This is the controller code @dleiftah. $data['educational_levels'] = $this->Place_model->get_edu_level_dropdown(TRUE);

Then continue on this code......   public function get_edu_level_dropdown ($all_option = FALSE)
 {
  $education_levels_list = $this->get_edu_levels();

  if (!$education_levels_list)
   return FALSE;

  $dropdown_array = array();

  if ($all_option)
   $dropdown_array[''] = lang ('all_all');

  foreach ($education_levels_list as $education_level)
   $dropdown_array[$education_level->tag] = $education_level->name;

  return $dropdown_array;
 }

Comment: So you're pulling the education values from the database ... When the form is submitted, are you saving the values back to the database so that you're pulling them correctly on the next page load? Also, it looks like the array values are coming from `$education_level->name` and you're checking if a number is in the array; for instance does `$education_level->name == 1` for the first element? Show a `print_r($education_levels)` to ensure that you're checking the correct value ...

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work, I haven't checked the code myself.

```
var checkboxes = $('.checkbox_label');
for ( i = 0 ; i < checkboxes.length; i++ ) {
    checkboxes[i].prop('checked', true)
}
```

You have to add this to the form's submit button click event.

Comment: Can you put up more code? SO i can see how it went trying the above code?

Comment: OP is talking about : Do you want the same checkboxes to be checked again after the page reload. You get that?

Answer (score 0):

Do a `print_r($educational_levels)` to see if the array contains the values or not. Other than that I can't see anything unusual. Also make sure that this `$educational_levels` is a single dimentional array.
This works perfectly for me:

```
public function index()
{
    //$this->load->view('welcome_message');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $educational_levels = array('1', '3');
    echo form_checkbox('edu_level[]','1', in_array('1', $educational_levels));
}
```

You need to check if your array `$educational_levels` `contains values` and is `not empty!`.

Comment: YEs is a single dimentional array.